# How to solve the RuntimeError: no running event loop in this time display project?

Tags: python, datetime, tkinter, asynchronous

Hey I am facing the problem to run the timestamp on terminal. This is my code, and when I'm tryin to run the code,

it pops up an error like this:
RuntimeError: no running event loop
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'TimeDisplayApp.display_time' was never awaited

May I know the way to solve it?

```
import tkinter as tk
import asyncio
import datetime
import pytz

class TimeDisplayApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Time Display App")

        self.display_time_button = tk.Button(root, text="Display Time", command=self.start_display)
        self.display_time_button.pack()

        self.close_time_display_button = tk.Button(root, text="Close Time Display", command=self.stop_display)
        self.close_time_display_button.pack()
        self.close_time_display_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

        self.timestamp_label = tk.Label(root, text="")
        self.timestamp_label.pack()

        self.display_task = None
        self.update_gui()

    def start_display(self):
        self.display_time_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.close_time_display_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        self.display_task = asyncio.create_task(self.display_time())

    def stop_display(self):
        self.display_time_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        self.close_time_display_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        if self.display_task:
            self.display_task.cancel()
            self.timestamp_label.config(text="Time display stopped")

    async def display_time(self):
        kl_timezone = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur')
        while True:
            kl_time = datetime.datetime.now(kl_timezone)
            formatted_time = kl_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
            self.timestamp_label.config(text="Current time in Kuala Lumpur: " + formatted_time)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    def update_gui(self):
        self.root.update()
        self.root.after(1000, self.update_gui)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = TimeDisplayApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

To solve the problem shown and that the timestamp could be constantly updated on terminal once the 'display time button' is clicked.

Comment: You are running a tkinter event loop. That's not asyncio.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import asyncio
import tkinter as tk
import pytz
import datetime

class TimeDisplayApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Time Display")
        self.timestamp_label = tk.Label(root, text="")
        self.timestamp_label.pack()
        self.update_time()

    async def display_time(self):
        kl_timezone = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur')
        while True:
            kl_time = datetime.datetime.now(kl_timezone)
            formatted_time = kl_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
            self.timestamp_label.config(text="Current time in Kuala Lumpur: " + formatted_time)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    def update_time(self):
        asyncio.create_task(self.display_time())
  
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = TimeDisplayApp(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).